# Importar base de datos mysql en MacOS con Java

Tags: java, mysql, bash, macos, importación

Verán, estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema de inventario para una Mac, el programa funciona correctamente, pero cuando quiero importar la Base de Datos SQL desde el programa, indica que la exportación se ha realizado correctamente, pero revisando el contenido de la BD, esta se encuentra vacía.
He usado el siguiente comando:

```
backup =  "cmd /c mysql --host=localhost -u "+Conexion.getUsu()+" "+Conexion.getBD()+" < "+ruta;
```

Dicho comando sólo me funciona el Windows, para Mac he usado el siguiente:

```
backup =  "/bin/bash mysql --host=localhost -u "+Conexion.getUsu()+Conexion.getBD()+" < "+ruta;
```

Para el caso del primer código, este no funciona en Mac, pero con el segundo, ejecuta la instrucción, pero la base de datos no es importada.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo se puede solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en cuanto al hilo lector seria este metodo:

```
 public class HiloLector extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;

        public HiloLector(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                int leido = is.read(buffer);
                while (leido > 0) {
                    String texto = new String(buffer, 0, leido);
                    System.out.print(texto);
                    leido = is.read(buffer);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que los respaldos de base de datos en MySQL se realizan haciendo uso de `mysqldump`.

Ahora bien, tu ruta esta hacia (`/bin/bash mysql --host=localhost -u ...`).

Aconsejo que pruebes de esta manera:

```
    String usuario = "nombre de tu usuario en la bd";
    String pass = "clave en casoq ue uses";
    String db = "nombre de tu base de datos";
                 
    int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Esta seguro de Respaldar la base de datos?");
    if (resp == 0) {

        try {
            JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
            int opcion = seleccionar.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (opcion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String ruta = seleccionar.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                String nomberespaldo = ruta + ".sql";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C://xampp//mysql//bin//mysqldump -u " + usuario + " -p" + pass + " --routines -R " + db);
                new HiloLector(p.getErrorStream()).start();
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nomberespaldo);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                int leido = is.read(buffer);
                while (leido > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, leido);
                    leido = is.read(buffer);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La base de datos se respaldo correctamente");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmBaseDatos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

de este modo la ruta esta orientada hacia la ubicación de MySQL, en mi caso esta en `"C://xampp//mysql//bin//mysqldump -u"` ya tu debes usar la ruta que uses en tu MySQL,
El anterior codigo lo puedes probar haciendo en un jbutton.
nota: en caso de no tener rutinas en tu bd omite esta parte  `--routines -R " +`

Answer (score 0):

en caso de que deses restaurar la base de datos el proceso seria este:

```
String usuario = "nombre de tu usuario en la bd";
String pass = "clave en casoq ue uses";
String db = "nombre de tu base de datos";

int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Esta seguro de Restaurar la base de datos?");
if (resp == 0) {
    try {

        JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
        int opcion = seleccionar.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (opcion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String ruta = seleccionar.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            String nomberestaurar = ruta ;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C://xampp//mysql//bin//mysql -u " + usuario + " -p" + pass + " " + db);
            new HiloLector(p.getErrorStream()).start();
            OutputStream is = p.getOutputStream();

            FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(nomberestaurar);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            int leido = fos.read(buffer);
            while (leido > 0) {
                is.write(buffer, 0, leido);
                leido = fos.read(buffer);
            }
            is.flush();
            is.close();
            fos.close();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La base de datos se restauro correctamente");
           }
        }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmBaseDatos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Saludos, @lucho, el código me ha funcionado bien, sólo que no hubo la necesidad de emplear el `HiloLector`, por lo demás muy bien, gracias.